# Can I move a virtualbox machine from windows to ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox

Does it work by moving VDI from windows to ubuntu VirtualBox folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find the virtualization files in "My Documents" in windows. These include not just the vdi file but some othe files too.
Move these files to the home folder in ubuntu. Preferrably in the virtualbox folder. You can then run the vdi file using virtualbox

Comment: FYI - These are in a folder and not directly placed. Just saying.

Comment: I think @iloveubuntu is asking how to move it from windows to unbuntu, not the other way around.

Comment: Oh sorry for that. I read it the other way round